What's the linearization of the product between a discrete variable and a continuous varibale?
I am trying to linearize the product $z=xy$, where $x$ is an integer variable and $y$ a continuous variable, both non-negative, for an optimization problem. I have tried the SCIP formulation:
$v_{bn} \leq u_{yn}x_b$
$v_{bn} \leq y_n$
$v_{bn} \geq y_n-u_{yn}(1-x_b)$
$o_n + \sum_{i+j=n} \sum_{l=0}^{L-1} 2^l v_{iL+l,j} = 2^L o_{n+1}+z_n $
where $v_{bn}, o_n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, and $u$ and $l$ the upper and lower bounds of each variable.
However, either I have programmed it incorrectly or it hasn't worked for my problem. I haven't found literature about this problem, as all I have found is on products of binary with continuous variables, discrete with binary, or two continuous variable.
Does anyone have any suggestion on how to linearize this constraint?

Does this help?  Linearize a product of an integer variable (not just binary) and a continuous variable?

See the second part of this answer: https://or.stackexchange.com/a/7294/500
